# php linebreak causes string value to disappear

Tags: php, line-breaks

I have some php querying and printing the info of a mysql table on a medical recruitment website.
Sometimes the users enter, causing line breaks where I would rather not have them, because
it affects the layout of the rendered HTML table in a way that it shouldn't.

I can trim the strings when they fill in the forms and the data get written into the table, but there's already a lot of data there, so i decided to remove the line breaks on the page
where php reads and prints the results.

**i declared one of the strings where this causes trouble as such:**

```
$specialtr = trim($special, "\n");
```

**and then where the html table gets rendered:**

```
echo '<td width="150">' . $specialtr . '</td>';
```

**Here is the whole code:**

All the code works, it's only the parts above that I added that now causes the column with $specialtr variable not to print/print as empty.

```
    <form action="selected.php" method="POST">
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width: 98%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<tr>
<td>
<?php
$dbhost = 'xxx';
$dbuser = 'xxx';
$dbpass = 'xxx';
$dbname = 'xxx';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error($conn));
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error($conn));

$specialtr = trim($special, "\n");

echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">';

$query = 'SELECT userid FROM employee
      ORDER BY userid ASC';
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));

$num_entries = mysql_num_rows($result); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
foreach ($row as $value) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="employee" value="' . $row['userid'] . '"/></td>';
echo '<td>Select</td>';
}
}

echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';

?>

</td>
<td>

<?php
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width: 98%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">';
echo '<tr>';
$query = 'SELECT userid, name, surname, sex, age, nationality, email, telnr, special FROM employee
      ORDER BY userid ASC';
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
extract($row);
echo '<td>' . $userid . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $surname . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $sex . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $age . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $nationality . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $email . '</td>';               
echo '<td>' . $telnr . '</td>';                
echo '<td width="150">' . $specialtr . '</td>';  
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

The code worked well enough, but since I added the trim, that entire column (the $special column disappears).

I hope maybe someone can tell me why it disappears or if my syntax has a little mistake.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your DB host/username/password... you should probably change your password RIGHT AWAY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `extract()` like that is a horrible thing. The function should be avoided as a general rule.

Also note that you're doing your `trim()` call BEFORE $special is defined, so your $specialtr variable is going to be an empty string. Calling the function before you start fetching your database results and extracting a result row into $special will not magically apply `trim()` to reach row you've fetched. If you want the results to be trimmed as you fetch them, then you have to apply the trim AFTER you do the fetch:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['userid'] . '</td>';
    ...
    echo '<td width="150">' . trim($row['special']) . '</td>';  
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```